# Is colon notation (:) equal to array(vector)

Tags: matlab

I have wrote a small program to test some funnction.

This is the proram:

```
close all;
clear all;

f = @(x, n) power(-1,(n-1)./2) .* power(x, n) ./ factorial(n);

n = [0,3,5,10,50,100];
% n = 0:10:100;
x = linspace(0, 4*pi, 1000);
ax = axes('nextplot', 'add');

for k = 1:length(n)
    plot(ax, x, f(x, n(k)), 'displayname', ['f_', int2str(n(k)), '(x)']);
end
```

The main problem for me is that I thought that colon notation(1:10) definies array with values equaliy spread.

In my program that is not the case.

There is difference in output of the program when I set n as [0,3,5,10,50,100] and if I set n as 0:10:100.

In the first version, with array, the program works fine, but wit the second version, with colon notation, the program does not work it simply draws a line at 0.

So my question is way this is happening? I mean if the colon notation and the array definition are the same why does the program has different output for the colon notation and array notation?

Did I missunderstod something?

Thanks!!

EDIT:
This are the plots that I get:
First id array notation, second is colon notation.
I am using mathlab R2013a

[image: Array Notation]

[image: Colon notation]

Comment: It does give similar output to me in both cases: several lines plotted, with imaginary part ignored. Maybe post your figures?

Comment: @LuisMendo I have added plots

Comment: This has nothing to do with colon notation. It's your f function that gives imaginary results, which are not plotted.

Comment: @OlegKomarov how can I correct that

Comment: Do you expect imaginary results? Possibly there's a typo in your anonymous function. Since we don't know what function you're trying to implement, we can't say what the issue is.

Comment: I don't see why this question gets down-voted to the abysses.

Comment: @Jigg In part because it could be solved in 5 seconds by OP by printing out the two vectors `n=[0,3,5,10,50,100]` and `n=0:10:100` and seeing whether they are the same or not. I think it's fair to expect someone to put that level of effort into a question before asking it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your commented line,

```
% n=[0:10:100];
```

you create a vector with values from 0 to 100, with spacing 10, ie `[0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100]`.

With your uncommented line,

```
n=[0 3 5 10 50 100];
```

you have the values you specify.

Since they're not the same input, you won't get identical output.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!!